# a user is logged in and on one of our domains or gets redirected to an error page

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, google-signin

This is an ongoing problem and I have asked questions multiple times. This post is to condense it all together so it will be easier to understand.

**What is needed:**

If a person directly types out a php location, such as www.mywebsite.com/dir/file.php, I want it to redirect to an error page because they have not logged in with one of my companies 6 google domains. The following is what has been figured out, **BUT** no matter if the person logs in with a correct domain, it gets directed to the error page.

**login.php**

```
<?php 
 session_start();
 include_once ("header.php");
 include '../default.php';
 include ('../' . $domain . '/variables.php');
 ?>
 <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
          <script type="text/javascript">
                function post(path, params, method) {
                    method = method || "post"; 
                    var form = document.createElement("form");
                    form.setAttribute("method", method);
                    form.setAttribute("action", path);

                    for(var key in params) {
                        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            var hiddenField=document.createElement("input");
                            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
                            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

                            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
                         }
                    }

                    document.body.appendChild(form);
                    form.submit();
                }


            function onSignIn(googleUser) {
                // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
                var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
                console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); 
                console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

                // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
                var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
                console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);

                var id = id_token;
                var emailAccount = profile.getEmail();

                if (id_token !="")
                {
                    post('login_process.php',{emailAccount:emailAccount} );
                } 
             };
            </script>
      </div>
```

This sends it to the next page

**login_process.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$email = $_POST['emailAccount'];
$allowed = array('domain1', 'domain2', 'domain3', 'domain4');
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    $explodedEmail=explode('@',$email);
    $auth = array_pop($explodedEmail);

    if (in_array($auth, $allowed))
    {
        header('Location: wiki.php');
        exit();
    }
}
    header('Location: error.php');
    exit();
?>
```

Here is where I believe it goes wrong. Once it gets to wiki.php, it instantly redirects back to error.php even if I am correctly logged in.

**wiki.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['emailAccount']) || $_SESSION['emailAccount'] != 1)
  {
             // user is not logged in redirects to error.php
       header("Location: error.php");
  }
  else
  {
       // user is logged in and loads this page
  }
include '../default.php';
include ('../' . $domain . '/variables.php');
?>
```

I don't know what is causing this problem as I am fairly new to PHP. Personally, I believe that the issue is somewhere on the wiki.php page. I just want to get this fixed and I do not know where to go from here. What I am guessing is that the domain is not being carried over to the page. Please help, and sorry for asking multiple questions that all apply to this. That's why I am putting it all together in this one spot.

Comment: Yes, they are actually quoted correctly in the actual file, I just didn't want to show the actual domain names and simply forgot to replace the correct quotations. Sorry about that.

Comment: Where are you setting `$_SESSION['emailAccount']`?

Comment: Here, give this a whirl `$_SESSION['emailAccount'] = $_POST['emailAccount'];` right after `$email = $_POST['emailAccount'];`. - and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: I was told by a co-worker that that the emailAccount would be posted with post('login_process.php',{emailAccount:emailAccount} );

Comment: its also hard to say where that POST array is being populated from and if it has a name attribute for it and possibly an additional "id". Error reporting will tell you that, as will checking your console.

Comment: With adding $_SESSION['emailAccount'] = $_POST['emailAccount']; to the login_process php it is still allowing me to put www.domain/dir/wiki.php into my browser and pulling the page up. It should be redirecting to the error.php page though.

Comment: Then this `$_SESSION['emailAccount'] != 1` hard to say where that session array is being assigned as "1".

Comment: Wait, I'm a little confused. Should $_SESSION['emailAccount'] != 1 be on the login_process.php or wiki.php?

Comment: @SamO'Day - you need to set the value when someone logs in; you check the value when you want to see if they have access.

Comment: Yeah, this is my problem. I don't know how to do that. I'm honestly surprised I even got this far. This project was thrown at me even though I have very little experience with it. I appreciate the help.